# Delete Database in Sqflite package in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

I am using the package 'sqflite' in flutter and I could not find a way to delete the entire database when the user in my app clicks on 'Delete Account'.

There are methods to delete data in a table but is there a way to delete the entire database using the package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a delete database function in the **DatabaseFactory** that can delete a database based on path.

```
Future<void> deleteDatabase(String path) =>
    databaseFactory.deleteDatabase(path);
```

See documentation for more information: https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite_common/latest/sqlite_api/DatabaseFactory-class.html

Comment: I didn't know databaseFactory was an inbuilt method in sqflite package. Thanks for the answer.